# CHKDSK finds no errors but drive keeps on failing

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, ntfs, hardware-failure, chkdsk

So here is the problem: I have an external disk that I use to store all the archived data, e.g. photos, movies, etc. The drive is formatted as NTFS, and checking the `Disk Management` tool from the `Computer Management` utility I can verify it is one single partition.

Running `CHKDSK` (and I tried with various options like `/f`, `/r`, `/B`, `/scan`, and practically all the options available) does not detect any problems. A sample output can be seen below.

```
1465136127 KB total disk space.
 913208424 KB in 61256 files.
     21724 KB in 6102 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    233223 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 551672756 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 366284031 total allocation units on disk.
 137918189 allocation units available on disk.
```

**However**, very recently after some, what many people may call, random event, I lost a lot of my pictures. This is also the reason why I ran all the test to verify that nothing is wrong. When I attempt to start `Recuva`, this is what I get:

```
Failed to scan the following drives:
E:: Unable to determine the file system type
```

And if that was not enough, at random points the drive will simply **hang**, that means that I may stop seeing it in `My Computer` or I may be able to see the icon but I not access it. Rebooting the computer does not solve it. I have to turn the power of the external drive off and then on again.

Any suggestions? Is it possible that there is a hardware error that `CHKDSK` cannot detect? Is there another tool that can find those kind of problems?

Comment: Plausible/possible fault: Power feed too weak (for USB) or broken (external feed), alternatively a broken USB-hub (or IT's power feed) if you have one.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case. I was afraid of that so I replaced the USB data cable and the hard disk is fed with an outside power source (connected to the plug).

Comment: Check and update driver if possible, if specific driver for the brand and no updates available, try to find a general one or vice versa.

Comment: `Unable to determine the file system type` looks like a driver or partitioning problem as I re-read.

Comment: Chkdsk checks the file system only. It detects bad sectors because files are located there and are incomplete per the checksum of the file system, but It cannot detect, hardware failures that don't cause file ststem errors

Comment: To eliminate the USB I would recommend plugging the disk directly into the computer by the SATA (?) Interface. If you continue to have problems then the next step is to source an exact same disk controller board to rule out the disk's own control circuits (ebay? Source an identical disk as a donor etc. - it must be identical even the firmware!). If the controller still gives same results then it'll be to a data recovery specialist if the data is that important to you (it'll cost an arm and a leg though!).

Comment: @Hannu It indeed sounds like a partition problem, this is why I made sure that everything "looks" relatively fine through the Disk Management, and they do :( . As for the device driver, well that's a different issue. Right now I am just using the one detected automatically by Windows.

Comment: @BigChris Wow, yeah that is indeed the "nuclear" approach, and it sounds complete and comprehensive and thanks for that. I did retrieve (at least most of) my data with other software and many hundreds hours of deep scanning. But I guess the real question is if there is way to find out if that was just a fluke or if there is a deeper problem, in which case I should immediately stop using that drive.

Comment: If you've got all your most important data retrieved and now backed up then is it worth still using the disk? I'd make sure I've got a backup (and another just to be sure) and chuck the disk. Is it worth continuing with a disk that will inevitably give you more problems sooner rather than later...?

Comment: Use mhdd or spinrite to evaluate the condition of the hard drive.  Additional, these utilities, especially spinrite, could fix some of the bad sectors, if that is the problem.

Comment: photorec and/or testdisk by cgsecurity if the physical structure is good.

Comment: @cybernard Thanks! I will give them a shot when I get home. Great fun for Halloween night :P SpinRite also came up in a conversation I had at work so I keep some hopes for it!

Comment: OK, so I used a utility similar to SpinRite called HDD Regenerator. I only detected some delays but no bad sectors. Therefore everythinks **seems** to ok. Truth be told, after running these tests/fixes, I had no issue. Now I am wondering whether it was a software fluke, e.g. you try to safely remove a drive, it fails cause the device is busy and then it actually unmounts it at a "random" time point causing unpredictable effects. Just a maybe. Anyway, thanks everyone for the amazing help!